# javascript match returning word boundry

Tags: javascript, regex

RegEx is not my strong suit. I hope one of you can help me.

I am trying to use javacript.match() to search for all hashed(# at the beginning) words.
and I get a returned white space.

```
string = "#foo #bar"
result = string.match(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig);
console.log(result)
```

Results in:

```
 ["#foo", " #bar"]
```

Notice the whitespace in #bar.
What should I change to my RegEx to exclude the boundary in the return to .match?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `(^|\W)` before as `#` is considered non word character anyway. You are getting space because `\W` will match space also.

This regex would work better:

```
var re = /(?:^|\s)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/g,
    matches = [],
    input = "#foo #bar abc#baz";
while (match = re.exec(input)) matches.push(match[1].trim());

console.log(matches);
//=> ["#foo", "#bar"]
```

**EDIT:** To avoid loops:

```
var m = [];
var str = "#foo #bar abc#baz";
str.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/g, function($1) { m.push($1.trim()); return $1; } );

console.log(m);
//=> ["#foo", "#bar"]
```

Comment: Ive edited the original question to reflect that I am looking for words that begin with the hash.  The regex you, kindly provided, would allow for hash in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this syntax to extract capture groups:

```
var str = '#foo #bar';
var myRegexp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\W)(#[^\\W_][\\w-]*)', 'g');

var matchResult = myRegexp.exec(str);
var result = Array();

while (matchResult != null) {
    result.push(matchResult[1]);
    matchResult = myRegexp.exec(str);
}

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want to loop through the match results, you can use this trick:

```
var str = '#foo #bar';
var result = Array();

str.replace(/(?:^|\W)(#[^\W_][\w-]*)/g, function (m, g1) { result.push(g1); } );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Humm , I had wanted to avoid looping through my results.
Thanks for the response.

Comment: @cs45977: I don't think there is another way. Or perhaps using the replace method with a closure as replacement.